# How to get back the default Delphi behavior at CTRL+Shift+V when CNPack is installed

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi XE, but the same issue already bothered me when using Delphi 2007. 
When CNPack IDE Wizards are installed, the default functionality when pressing CTRL+Shift+V is changed.

Usually a local variable is being automatically created. CNPack changes this to moving the cursor to the var section of the current method.

How can i prevent CNPack from doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

- go to the **CnPack / Code Editor Wizard / Options** menu item
- find the **Toggle Var Field Tool** in the **Editor Tools** grid
- change the shortcut or disable the tool using **Enable this Tool** check box

Comment: Great, the shortcut needs to be changed in this menu. Then the default behaviour is active again.

Comment: To confirm what Michael says, you need to change the shortcut to get back the default ctrl+shift+v behavior. Unchecking "Enable this Tool" isn't sufficient (at least in the current version). Also, even if you have disabled Code Editor Wizard altogether, you *still* have to change the shortcut.

Comment: In my case CNPack does not use this shortcut but still refractory won't work. Probably some other function is using this shortcut...